# Associate JavaScript Object Function to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say - On any `<UL>` element in page, I want to define a few behaviours. Such as...

- If you click on any `<li>` inside the `<ul>`, then its colour changes...
- If you double-click an `<li`>, then a new `<li>` gets appended at the end..
- and many other such behaviours ...

Now I know little jQuery using which I can write individual functions to accomplish these things....

- `$("ul li").on ('click', function () { ... .css() .. });`
- `$("ul li").on ('dblclick', function () { ... .append("<li>New Born Li</li>") ... });`

But what I really want to do is to encapsulate all these functions in a single object (class) like structure. Then I will just associate that function on any element to enable those functionalities on that element. Something like this -

```
$("ul").enableMySpecialULFeatures ({ 
   color: 'red',
   textToAppend: 'New Born Li' ,
   ... 
});
```

Once I call this function on `<ul>` then all the behaviours get applied on `<ul>`.

My Question is - how do I create this `enableMySpecialULFeatures` type of object function? Wondering if anyone can give me a boilerplate to get me started...

Comment: you define the method on $.fn and will be available to all collections.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am reading about `$.fn` now.. But how do I put the other behavioural functions (such as color changing and appending etc.) inside my new function?

Comment: you basically template out the hard-coded operations you have now to work on _this_ and the passed argument object instead of primitives. ex: ...append("<li>"+spec.textToAppend+"</li>")

Comment: would it be possible for you to show a simple example as Answer? I am less than 24-hrs old with JavaScript... A simple working example will get me started..

Comment: look like there's no need, answer looks close to what i would have done, even has defaults up top....

Comment: yes, my comment crossed the same time of the answer.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create js plugin like this:-

```
$.fn.enableMySpecialULFeatures = function(options) {
 var settings = $.extend({
     color: "#556b2f",
     textToAppend: 'New Born Li'
  }, options );

 return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find('li').click(function(){
     $(this).css('color',settings.color);
   });
   $(this).find('li').dblclick(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).append('<li>'+settings.textToAppend+'</li>');
     });
 });
};
```

and use:-

```
$(function(){
  $('ul').enableMySpecialULFeatures({
    color:'green',
    textToAppend:"hello"
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/935jfu0e/)

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need... please bear with me while I test it out.. Thanks!

Comment: It works brilliantly. I am assuming the `$(function(){ });` is a shortcut for jQuery's `$(document).ready()` right?

Comment: @hashbrown yes you can use `$(document).ready()` instread if you want

Answer (score 1):

And then improve @mohit-arora's example by using multiple event handlers on a single reference to `$(this)` in the return statement:

```
$.fn.enableMySpecialULFeatures = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
     color: "#556b2f",
     textToAppend: 'New Born Li'
  }, options );

  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').on({
      click: function(){
         $(this).css('color',settings.color);
      },
      dblclick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).append('<li>'+settings.textToAppend+'</li>');
      }
    });
 });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Elise... I have accepted Mohit's reply as Answer but I do consider your suggestion on using multiple event handlers on single reference to *this*.